# Iptables error prevents Pod starting in Kubernetes

Tags: linux, kubernetes, iptables

I'm setting up a Kubernetes cluster following Kelseys Lab: https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way

I have only set up one node so far. When trying to deploy a Pod, the following error prevents it from getting started:

`Warning FailedSync Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "SetupNetwork" for "nginx-3137573019-pjbie_default" with SetupNetworkError: "Failed to setup network for pod \"nginx-3137573019-pjbie_default(b4128fc1-6707-11e6-a8b3-005056a2068d)\" using network plugins \"kubenet\": Failed to execute iptables-restore: exit status 1 (Can't open /tmp/kube-temp-iptables-restore-214792160: Permission denied\n); Skipping pod"`

The kubelet runs as root. The files mentioned in the log also belong to root.

System is Linux OEL 7 (Kernel: UEK 4.1.12)

Does anyone have an idea, what the cause could be or how to investigate further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like SELinux is preventing `kubelet` from performing changes on IPtables. Search for messages containing the string 'AVC' inside `/var/log/audit/audit.log` in order to confirm that theory.

The easiest workaround is to disable SELinux altogether with the shell command `setenforce 0`. This doesn't survive a reboot, so make sure you also disable SELinux in `/etc/selinux/config`.

If you don't want to disable SELinux completely, which I'd recommend, you will have to use tools like `audit2allow` and `semodule` in order to build your own SELinux module for `kubelet` and `kube-proxy`.

Check these references for further guidance:

- [RHEL7 - SELinux troubleshooting](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/chap-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Troubleshooting.html#sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Troubleshooting-What_Happens_when_Access_is_Denied)
- [RHEL7 - Allowing Access: audit2allow](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Troubleshooting-Fixing_Problems.html#sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Fixing_Problems-Allowing_Access_audit2allow)